# How can I create and access list of list of list.. in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a particular requirement where I don't know beforehand how many levels of branching is required. I need the data structure to be a list since I also don't know how many elements will I be storing in each branch.

Right now I am hard coding the branching to be either 1,2,3,4 or 5. I initially thought that I would never require more than 3 levels of hierarchy. Although that is not the case now. I am already down to 5 levels; each time just updating the code below.

```
  # list of lists of lists of ...
  # i.e. declaring the data structure that holds the indices for each portfolio!
  l = vector("list", num_ports[1]);
  if(length(num_ports) > 1) {   for(i in 1:num_ports[1]) {

    l[[i]] = vector("list", num_ports[2]);

    if(length(num_ports) > 2) {   for(j in 1:num_ports[2]) {

      l[[i]][[j]] = vector("list", num_ports[3]);

      if(length(num_ports) > 3) {   for(k in 1:num_ports[3]) {

        l[[i]][[j]][[k]] = vector("list", num_ports[4]);

        if(length(num_ports) > 4) {   for(k in 1:num_ports[4]) {

          l[[i]][[j]][[k]][[p]] = vector("list", num_ports[5]);

          # more than 4 levels not allowed as of now!
          # index the list by: l[[i]][[j]][[k]][[p]][[q]] where q in 1:num_ports[5]

        }
        }
      }
      }
    }
    }
  }
  }
```

I know the array `num_ports` on which to create the hierarchy.

***Note:*** I update and access this list later on. The code there is even messier. I may never need more than 5 levels but the current way is far from elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can build your "empty" nested list:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) replicate(y, x, F), rev(num_ports), NULL)
```

for `num_ports <- c(2, 3)` both your solution and mine return:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
NULL

[[1]][[2]]
NULL

[[1]][[3]]
NULL


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
NULL

[[2]][[2]]
NULL

[[2]][[3]]
NULL
```

and it works for more complex cases as well.

Comment: Great solution! This is exactly what I needed. Thanks :)
Any thoughts on how can I access/update it using the same nomenclature as yours, i.e. which doesn't depend on the length of `num_ports` ?

Answer (score 3):

This can be simplified a lot.  `l[[i]][[j]][[k]][[p]]` is the same thing as `l[[c(i,j,k,p)]]`.  You can construct the vector of indices in any way you construct a vector, you don't need to know in advance how long it will be.